# 'invisible' row in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a Firebird database which shows 174 rows in the TDBGrid component in my Lazarus project but only 173 trows in the FlameRobin application.  The missing row is the last row and I have been trying to delete it.   I assume that the row haas become tagged in some way which FlameRobin recognises but TDBGrid doesnt and the tag is preventing deletion.   Just a guess so does anyone have experience of tyhis and/or suggestions to get rid of the row?

Comment: Could be a transaction visibility issue, is this reproducible after *both* applications have been restarted?

Comment: Yes - still there after several openings and closings and reboots.